# A bit confused, pretty sure i'm missing something here: Indexed array with an element from different array?

Tags: python, numpy

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfs3o.png)

I'm pretty confused on line 11 where np_heights was indexed by np_positions == "GK" **which is an element from a different array. (If i'm not mistaken)**

I've written that line as instructed in datacamp:
*Extract all the heights of the goalkeepers. You can use a little trick here: use np_positions == 'GK' as an index for np_heights. Assign the result to gk_heights.*

The code worked and says i got the correct answer, but still i'm pretty confused as to what happened in line 11. Can you really index an array with an element from a different array or am i just looking at this the wrong way? haha Thanks in advance!

Code is written as follows:

```
# heights and positions are available as lists

# Import numpy
import numpy as np

# Convert positions and heights to numpy arrays: np_positions, np_heights
np_positions = np.array(positions)
np_heights = np.array(heights)

# Heights of the goalkeepers: gk_heights 
gk_heights = np_heights[np_positions == "GK"]

# Heights of the other players: other_heights
other_heights = np_heights[np_positions != "GK"]

# Print out the median height of goalkeepers. Replace 'None'
print("Median height of goalkeepers: " + str(np.median(gk_heights)))
```

Comment: Please include relevant code as text in your question.

Comment: that syntax does not index one element, it filters the array, and returns the filtered array, i.e. the first one returns an array of all goalkeeper heights

Answer (score 0):

Comparison between `Numpy array` and a `String` would return an `array` of `True` or `False` and if we use it for an initialization like that you have mentioned in the question  an `array` of values corresponding to the `True` value will be initialized.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> positions = ["GK","Sf","RB"]
>>> hights = [6,6.1,7]
>>> np_positions = np.array(positions)
>>> np_heights = np.array(hights)

>>> np_positions == "GK"
array([ True, False, False])

>>> np_heights[np_positions == "GK"]
array([6.])

>>> gk_heights = np_heights[np_positions == "GK"]

>>> gk_heights
array([6.])
```